# FaLang Alias Conversion not working in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, multilingual, joomla-component

I have installed FaLang component to use multi-language support everything is working fine except the alias structure. When we are switching the language the URL not get changes as per the added alias conversion added into admin section. I tried almost all activities enabling both plugins but still the problem is as it is.

Comment: As far as I know that's a known bug with no solution to date.

Comment: I tried to fix it up but not found the solution. but i found that the code is exactly same as JoomFish it may be possible some functions not working properly

Answer (score 0):

I believe Shaz is correct, there is no solution within FaLang at this time.

I asked the developer about this in Feb 2012 and he mentioned he was still working on it, but currently, with FaLang v 1.1.7 it still doesn't happen.

Initially I was really excited when FaLang appeared, but now I'm not so sure. I work on a lot of multilingual sites, and I don't want to get get stranded with multilingual Joomla 2.5 sites as has happened to me with many Joomla 1.5 sites I developed with JoomFish.

I know many well respected developers like FaLang, but FWIW I now favour the native language capabability built into Joomla 2.5. It's not perfect, but for now they have my confidence that it will improve.

Unfortunately this doesn't solve your problem, but if you need an introduction to how it works, here is one good link:

```
[http://bit.ly/LpPoV2][1]  
and another one  
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnhVVtyejPg
```

Initially I found the process a bit cumbersome, but once I got used to it, it's works quite well ... and yes, the aliases work as you would expect.

Good luck!